# React Dnd useDrag condition canDrag is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I want the component will be draggable if the props variable (flag) is more then 3. I have used used React DnD useDrag with canDrag.
My code is

````
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => {
    const isDrag = flag >= 3;
    console.log(isDrag); // Here i have correct correct output
    return {
      type: ItemTypes.GAME,
      item: { id: `${row}_${col}`, row: row, col: col },
      options: {
        dropEffect: "copy",
      },
      collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
      canDrag: isDrag,
    };
  }, [flag, row, col]);
  const highlight =
    row == minDelta.row && col == minDelta.col
      ? `3px solid red`
      : "3px solid #e6e6e6";
  const tileColor = `rgb(${color.join(", ")})`;
  return (
    <Grid item xs>
      <StyledGridCell
        ref={drag}
        tilecolor={tileColor}
        highlight={highlight}
        title={tileColor}
      />
    </Grid>
  );
});
export default Tile;```

if i reverse the condition like canDrag : !isDrag then it works only when flag have default value that is 0 other wise it doesn't work. 
Also i have correct value at line 3.
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `isDrag` value to the dependency array.

```js
  const [{ isDragging }, drag] = useDrag(() => {
    const isDrag = flag >= 3;
    console.log(isDrag); // Here i have correct correct output
    return {
      type: ItemTypes.GAME,
      item: { id: `${row}_${col}`, row: row, col: col },
      options: {
        dropEffect: "copy",
      },
      collect: (monitor: DragSourceMonitor) => ({
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
      }),
      canDrag: isDrag,
    };
  }, [flag, row, col, isDrag]);
```

Comment: You can give more detailed answer it always help to understand it for the others